# Getting wrong coordinates on canvas on WVGA800

Tags: android

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        X = (int) event.getX();
        Y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            Toast.makeText(context, X + "-" +Y,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I'm trying to use this code to get the x and y coordinates of the canvas on WVGA800,
Android version 2.1

But I'm not getting the exact coordinates of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get the coordinates of the **screen**? Your code is actually getting the coordinates (reported by event) relative to your view/canvas. If screen coordinates is what you want, try using View.getLocationOnScreen to compute it based on the view coordinates.

```
X = (int) event.getX();
Y = (int) event.getY();
int[] position = new int[2];
position[0] = X;
position[1] = Y;
this.getLocationOnScreen(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        X = (int) event.getX();
        Y = (int) event.getY();

        Toast.makeText(context, X + "-" +Y,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

You will get the coordinates of the position where you touched down.

Comment: you will get the co-ordinates of the position where you touched down